# Service running as SYSTEM call an .exe to do work

Tags: c#, windows, service

I currently have a service that calls an .exe, the .exe gets called and is running as SYSTEM but this .exe takes flags which don't seem to be in play.

```
try
{
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = newSystem.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

strCmdText = @" -i -a -d: 123"

proc.FileName = Install.ToString() + "\\Process.exe";

proc.Arguments = strCmdText;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
}
catch (Exception errorprocess)
{
data.log(errorprocess.ToString());
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why it is calling the .exe but not running the flags.

I know it is running the .exe because I can see it in the Task Manager.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` on `strCmdText`?  Why not simply do `proc.Arguments = @" -i -a -d:" + 123'`....and what is the purpose of `+ 123`?

Comment: Sorry typos, I have edited to correct values.

Comment: Looks like Process init is all fine. Having space in between -d and 123 could cause issues. Try removing that space if you intend to pass 123 as a value for the argument -d

Comment: tried with out spaces still doesn't work...the .exe gets called and it runs forever never dies but the flags just aren't in play.

Comment: There's nothing special about a service in this respect.  Does the code work when it is run as a normal application?

Comment: Incidentally, Task Manager can show you the command line.  Or better still, use Process Explorer.